# In an English-speaking country, how would a household employee address their female employer?

Tags: greetings, forms-of-address

Would it be *Miss*? *Mistress*? *Madam*?

Or, should she be young (underage and/or unmarried): *Young Miss*? *Young Mistress*? *Young Lady*? *Young Madam*?

EDIT (to clarify):

How would a butler, chef, chauffeur, housekeeper, etc, address someone whom he/she works for in a wealthy family?

- If the employer is older, is it Miss? Or Mistress? Or Madam?
- Or if she is young, Young Miss? Young Mistress? Young Lady? Young Madam?

Comment: Who the heck still has ***masters*** and ***servants***??? Is this for fiction  of an imagined or bygone era?

Comment: @tchrist Fiction. Isn't it common? Even Alfred calls Batman Master Bruce.

Comment: You will probably need to specify the time and place.

Comment: I think "in an English-speaking country" is too broad, since forms of address vary across the globe - do you mean England, the US, Australia, India?

Comment: In the US it would usually "Sir" or "Ma'am" or "Mr. Smith" or "Mrs. Jones" (or "Miss Jones" for an unmarried woman).  Don't get us started on gender-neutral terms.

Comment: My housekeeper and my gardener both call me by my first name, and this is in Washington, which is more formal than much of the country. I'm only Mr. Choster to salesmen, flight attendants, and hospital personnel.

Comment: @ConanG I don't believe Alfred addresses Bruce Wayne as *master* because of the servant relationship, but because *master* is the equivalent of *mister* for a young boy, and a term that for them that has evolved over the years into a term of endearment.

Comment: @choster - So you're not going to make the (bogus) claim that *Batman* doesn't represent real life??  Whew!!

Answer (score 4):

People still employ cleaning ladies, dog-walkers, lawn-mowers, and snow shovelers; these are not full time servants who work only for this person, but they are household employees. In my experience in Canada the existence of an employer-employee relationship doesn't change what people call each other: an adult would call me Kate by default and a child might call me Mrs Gregory or Kate depending on their age and our existing relationship (eg neighbor children might have already been invited to call me Kate.)

If your question applies specifically to full time employees who work for only one family and share a home with them, then I would not be surprised to hear a more formal address (eg Mrs Gregory, or if I had a title perhaps Your Grace) simply to keep the distinction between friend/family/roomate and employee clear. Also certain occupations have a tendency to give their employees titles (eg nannies might call all the moms Mother, all the dads Father) -- these are occupations in which the employee is, to a certain extent, setting the rules of engagement. A pool boy would not do this. A tennis coach might.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose knowledge of such matters depends heavily on the stratum in which one was brought up. First-hand experience counts.

That said, I believe that a female employer older than 18 (or 21) would be addressed as

**Madam** (or ma'am, if you will)

while a younger individual would be

**Miss** **[** First Name, i.e. Mary, Jane, Gwendolyn, etc **]**

or

**Miss** **[** Surname, i.e. Johnson, Hamilton, Capet, etc **]**

Comment: And a married one might be **Mrs [** Surname **]**.

Comment: Where would these forms of address be common?

Comment: @1006a In a townhouse.